# How can I simplify a lattice xyplot with millions of data points?

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I have multiple sets of time history data collected at approximately 500 Hz for 12 hours at a time.

I've plotted this data using an `xyplot` with `type="l"` on a log time scale, as the phenomenon is largely a logarithmic decay.

The resulting plots are enormous pdf files that take a long time to render and inflate the file size of my sweaved document, as I assume each individual data point is being plotted, which is total overkill. The plots could be reasonably reproduced with orders of magnitude fewer points.

Switching to `type="smooth"` fixes the rendering and file size issue, but the loess smoothing drastically alters the shape of the lines, even after toying with the loess smoothing parameters, so I've given up on loess smoothing as an option here.

Is there a simple way to either post-process the plot to simplify it, or to sub-sample the data before plotting?

If subsampling the data, I would think that it would be beneficial to do so in a sort of inverse-log way, where data near zero has a high time frequency (use all 500 Hz from the source data), but as time goes on the frequency of data decreases (even 0.01 Hz would be more than sufficient near t=12 hours)--this would give a more-or-less equal plot resolution across the log time scale.

Comment: "but the loess smoothing drastically alters the shape of the lines": This raises alarm bells for me. What you're saying is basically that you fit a model, but that the model fit was very poor. Either your preconceptions of your data need to be adjusted, or you should adjust your model (change some of the loess settings, use a different smoother, etc.).

Comment: @joran you are absolutely correct. This is why I abandoned the loess smoothing. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: I'm just saying that a scatterplot smoother is the right way to go, you just haven't found the right one yet. You could try splines, or you could switch to ggplot, which provides a somewhat easier interface to a wider array of smoothers (`gam` in particular).

Comment: `pdf` will be slow because it uses vector graphics - would it work to use pixel based graphics?

Comment: @SeñorO This thought had occurred to me, a rasterization of the plot would fix the rendering and file size issues, but I'd like to stick with vector graphics if possible. Also, I haven't been able to figure out how to force generation of a raster format in the context of my sweave workflow.

Comment: I'd suggest hexbinning it. Package hexbin can do it, or if you want to map a third variable to colour/size check this out https://gist.github.com/geotheory/5748388

Comment: Apart from log time scale, I had exactly the same problem. Subsampling that you were thinking about is simple to implement and works very well. I would say, go for it.

Answer (score 1):

After trying `type="spline"` and again being unhappy with the extent to which it changes the shape of my data, I decided to go with a subsampling approach, where I reduced the data density before plotting.

The function I wrote will subsample along a log scale, so that the "plot resolution" is more or less constant.

```
## log.subsample(data,time,n.per.decade)

## subsamples a time-sampled data.frame so that there are no more than
## n.per.decade samples in each decade.

## usage
## data: data.frame, the data frame object, must contain a column with
##       times
##
## time: charater, the name of the data frame column with the time
##       values
## n.per.decade: the max number of rows per decade of time

## value
## returns a data.frame object with the same columns as data,
## subsampled such that there are no more than n.per.decade rows in
## each decade of time. Any rows in data with time < 0 are dropped.

log.subsample <- function(data,time,n.per.decade){
    time.col <- grep(x=colnames(data),pattern=time)
    min.time <- min(data[,time.col])
    if(min.time < 0){
        data <- data[data[,time.col]>0,]
        min.time <- min(data[,time.col])
        droplevels(data)
    }
    max.time <- max(data[,time.col])
    stopifnot(max.time > 0)
    min.decade <- floor(log10(min.time))
    max.decade <- ceiling(log10(max.time))

    time.seq <- seq(from=min.decade, to=max.decade, by=1/n.per.decade)
    time.seq <- 10^time.seq
    for(i in 1:length(time.seq)){
        tmp <- which(data[,time.col] >= time.seq[i])[1]
        if(!is.na(tmp)){
            if(!exists("indices.to.keep")){
                indices.to.keep <- tmp
            }
            else{
                indices.to.keep <- c(indices.to.keep,tmp)
            }
        }
    }
    indices.to.keep <- unique(indices.to.keep)
    result <- data[indices.to.keep,]
    result <- droplevels(result)
    return(result)
}
```

The only issue here is that if there are any "groups" in the data to plot, this subsampling function needs to be run on each group individually, and then a data frame needs to be built up to pass to `xyplot()`

It would be great if someone could tell me if it's possible to "inject" this subsampling routine into the `xyplot()` call somehow, such that it would be called for each individual group of data in turn, eliminating the need to break the data up, run the subsampling routine, and put the data back together before calling `xyplot()`

Comment: yes, if you write a panel function, but it's a little tricky.

Comment: @BenBolker I figured that's where it would go. I have some experience with panel functions, but not for processing the data itself. Could you point me to any examples?

Comment: For example: `d <- data.frame(x=runif(1000),y=runif(1000), f=sample(1:6,replace=TRUE,size=1000)); library(lattice); xyplot(y~x|f,data=d); xyplot(y~x|f,data=d, panel=function(x,y,...) { x <- x[1:10]; y <- y[1:10]; panel.xyplot(x,y,...)})` Alternatively, you could use `plyr::ddply` to automate the split-apply-combine loop ...